# How to advance slices like we advance ptr++ in in C++

Tags: rust

I'm trying to simulate the behavior of this C code in Rust:

```
len = av_parser_parse2(myparser, AVCodecContext, &data, &size,
                                 in_data, in_len,
                                 pts, dts, pos);
in_data += len;
```

`in_data` is a buffer. It can be advanced.

How can I do something similar with a slice? I know I can take a subslice, and I could even write a class that I can advance and then return a subslice.

But is there something in the default libraries that already does that? Something like a buffered slice reader? PS: one that does not copy again the slice, only owns it and returns subslices according to the `+=` operator on it.

Comment: Something in the default libraries that’s simpler than a subslice? It’s just `in_data = &in_data[len..];`.

Comment: FWIW, [`&[u8]` implements `std::io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-10), although this only works for byte slices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're not trying to move the end of the slice, you can reslice it with something like `in_data = &in_data[len..]`